# Merging two lists with possible duplicates (C#)

Tags: c#, list, linq, merge, duplicates

I have two lists with objects containing three properties. If two or more objects in these lists have the same value of two of these properties, then they are considered duplicates, and we must pick one to keep based on some logic.

The properties are as follows:

- Role
- Interest
- Declaration

If Role and Interest are equal for any objects in a list, we must check the value of Declaration from among all the duplicates. If it is either "Yes" or "No", then the object with the earliest date is kept. If the value is "Calculated", then that object with the earliest date is kept. (i.e. "Yes" and "No" trumps "Calculated")

The final merged list should contain no duplicates of Role and Interest, and the Declaration value should be valid based on the logic above.

The concatList contains all elements from both list1 and list2.

So far I've tried to save the duplicate objects in a new list and looping over those to add the correct one to the merged list. However, I am not sure what logic is needed to take into account the "Calculated" declaration values. The duplicates are being ordered by CreatedOn in descending order, but I can't make sure that the "Calculated" duplicates are not being added first.

I also don't like how with my current solution, I have a nested foreach loop. I would much rather avoid that if possible.

My question is how I can structure my logic to add the correct item among the duplicates. Any input would be appreciated, thanks.

```
var concatList = list1.Concat(list2);
var listAfterMerge = new List<object>();

        foreach (var item in concatList )
        {
            var duplicates = concatList.Where(x => x.Role == item.Role && x.Interest == item.Interest);

            if (duplicates .Count() > 1)
            {
                foreach (var duplicate in duplicates .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn))
                {
                    if(duplicate.Declaration.Value == "Yes" || 
                       duplicate.Declaration.Value == "No")
                    {
                        listAfterMerge.Add(duplicate);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         ...?
                    }
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                listAfterMerge.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe IComparer<> if your object is concrete.

Comment: `Union` maybe: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Union__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__. You write a complicated comparer and go to town?

Answer (score 2):

If you group all the duplicates together (with `GroupBy`) then for each group, you can order it so any "Yes"/"No" are first (I test for != "Calculated" since you only listed the three cases), followed by any "Calculated" and then by `CreatedOn` ascending, then take the first element of each group. If a group only contains one element, the result will be the one element.

```
var ans = concatList.GroupBy(t => new { t.Role, t.Interest })
                    .Select(tg => tg.OrderBy(t => t.Declaration == "Calculated")
                                    .ThenBy(t => t.CreatedOn)
                                    .First())
                    .ToList();
```

Note: Booleans are sorted so true > false, so can just test for "Calculated"

Answer (score 1):

Using the GroupBy LINQ operator will really simplify this.

```
var concatList = list1.Concat(list2);
var groups = concatList.GroupBy(i => (i.Role, i.Interest));
//for each group of matching role, interest return a single item
var merged = groups.Select(g => {
    //if no duplicates
    if (g.Count() == 1)
        return g.First();

    var ordered = g.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedOn);

    //get first "Yes/No" item
    var yn = ordered.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Declaration == "Yes" || x.Declaration == "No");

    if (yn != null)
        return yn;

    //if no "Yes/No" items, return first "Calculated"
    //Note: this assumes that the only possible values are yes, no or calculated. Otherwise, comparison against "Calculated" should be added
    return ordered.First();
});

return merged.ToList();
```

Comment: `OrderByDescending().FirstOrDefault()` is the latest item, not the earliest item?

Comment: @NetMage you're right. Fixed. I was just copying from the code he already had in the question.